# Can I use a WinForms VB.NET application to access a database on a centralized server?

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, winforms, application-design

I want to connect a database that is located on centralized server. How can I use a windows form VB.NET application to access it? Is this possible?

How can I maintain a single user entry (e.x== used of INSERT command)?

Are both of the above things possible? If so, how can I go about implementing them?

Comment: How is this question different from your previous question: "Is sql server needed for run a vb.net windows form solution with Sql database as back end ??????"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use VB .NET to access a database.  You'll want to look into things called "[ADO .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021%28VS.71%29.aspx)" or "[LINQ to SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx)" or "[Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28VS.80%29.aspx)" for various ways of interacting with the database.  There's no shortage of tutorials out there for getting started.

I'm afraid the second part of your question is unclear.  Using a comparison operator instead of an INSERT command?  Please elaborate.